# Swift, what is hasBasket() method and what is its functions?

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and is trying to learn the concept of subclass. The Swift Programming language 2.1 states:

Subclasses "defines a new stored property, hasBasket, with a default value of false (inferring a type of Bool for the property)."

I have searched google but is unable to find a satisficatory answer to what is hasBasket() method and what is its functions? Could someone please help me out? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hasBasket` is just an example to explain you the concept.

```
class Bicycle: Vehicle {
    var hasBasket = false
}
```

You define a type `Bicycle` which extends a `Vehicle` and specializes it (so it's still a `Vehicle` but with added behavior). The `hasBasket` property is indeed an example of a specialization, since a bicycle could have a basket then you add that property to the `Bicycle` class.

So that this is legal:

```
let bicycle = Bicycle()
bicycle.hasBasket = true
```

And if you define a new type which derives from `Bicycle` as

```
class Tandem: Bicycle {
    var currentNumberOfPassengers = 0
}
```

then this would be legal too:

```
let tandem = Tandem()
tandem.hasBasket = true
```

since subclassing makes the child class inherit all the behavior of its parent.